# supremum: some relations about concluding step

Tags: real-analysis

I  don't understand
$$ a > \sup ( A ) - \frac \epsilon 2 $$
$$ b > \sup ( B ) - \frac \epsilon 2 $$
$$ a + b > \sup ( A ) + \sup ( B ) - \epsilon $$
how do we conclude that $ \sup ( A ) + \sup ( B ) \le \sup ( A + B ) $?

I also want to ask how to study this course; can you recommend anything because I am struggling this course?

Comment: I assume your epsilon is greater than zero. Do you understand why we always seems to be subtracting a positive number from $\sup(\text{whatever})\;?$

Comment: I highly encourage Abbott's book Understanding Analysis. I used it when I took Real Analysis, and I found it pretty easy to read while not glossing over details.

Comment: thank you soo much @Isaiah

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the following theorem, which is used in Analysis very often, and usually without mention:

**Theorem:** Let $x, y$ be real numbers, and suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $$x \ge y - \epsilon.$$
Then, $x \ge y$.

*Proof: (Informal)* How do we prove this? Contradiction is always good to try. Assume $x < y$, and imagine them on the number line. It looks like this:

$----x --- (gap) --- y -----$

$x$ is to the left of $y$. So if we can find an $\epsilon^*$ such that $y - \epsilon^*$ is in the gap, then we can get a contradiction, because $y - \epsilon^* > x$. How can we find such an $\epsilon^*$? We can find a number $z^*$ in the gap, and then we can take $\epsilon^* = y - z^*$, and it should work. How can we find a number $z^*$, in the gap between $x$ and $y$? Well the average of $x$ and $y$, $(x + y)/2$ should be in that gap, so we can use $\epsilon^* = y - \frac{x+y}{2} = \frac{y-x}{2}.$

As an exercise, you should write this proof formally.

Now, for the main question:

We showed $a + b > \sup ( A ) + \sup ( B ) - \epsilon$. For every $\epsilon > 0$. Now $\sup(A+B)$ is supposed to be $\ge$ than any element in $A+B$, so in particular $\sup(A+B) \ge a + b$ for this $a$ and $b$. Thus

$$\sup(A+B) \ge \sup(A) + \sup(B) - \epsilon.$$

Now apply the theorem.

Comment: thank you for your clear explation. Can you recommend any book to study this topic? or any youtube channel

Comment: @llee7jkonn Yes. The book Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott, it has very good explanations.